# MVC: Setting a key for a type in a model class that has been auto generated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4 and Razor (CSHTML).
I used Entity Framework 6 to auto generate the AdventureWorks2012 database MVC models.
I created a New folder DAL (Data Access Layer) and created my DataContext class in this folder.

```
using AdventureWorks_site.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace AdventureWorks_site.DAL
{
    public class AdventureWorksContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention 
            // If you keep this convention, the generated tables  
            // will have pluralized names. 
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }    
    }    
}
```

When I try to create a Controller based on the Person class and the AdventureWorksContext above it presents an error message saying that the Person class does not have a key and therefore it fails. I can modify the class and add a key, however, since it is an auto generated class it is possible that it will need to be generated again at some point reverting any changes I would make. Is there a way to assign a key possibly from the context class? Or can someone please offer a different approach.

Comment: Does the Person table in the database have a key?

Comment: I did not even think to check that. But yes. It is PK_Person_BusinessEntityID. I am using the AdventureWorks2012 database.

Comment: Then you need to figure out why the auto-generation process is not including that information. How are you generating it?

Comment: Very good point. I can see the "key" column in the class but it was not generated as a key column. I added the ADO.NET Entity Data Model by right clicking the model folder and following the steps of adding the database I desired. (Entity Framework 6.0)

Comment: Refreshing the model from the database doesn't help?

Comment: I re-saved Model1.tt file which I believe will auto generate the class files but no luck. Either way I just created the Entity Data Model files and have not modified them. I will have to play around with this some more after doing a bit more research on how the model class files are auto generated. I am trying to teach myself to build MVC web applications. I might need to visit BN and grab a quick reference book.

Comment: One final question for now, do any of the other tables in your model have keys, is it just this one table missing it?

Comment: Many of the tables have keys. I am looking at the Model1.edmx which shows a diagram of the database entities and it shows that BusinessEntityID is the key for the Person entity. That's a head scrather as this is not represented in the actual model class code.